# OnDelete Event Receiver delete associated item

Tags: 2010, event-receivers, delete

I have 2 lists. List A creates a record in List B on the creation of a record in List A. So, I'd like to complete the circle by deleting the the item in List B when the record is deleted in List A.

The relation is as follows:

> List A
>   --------- EmpName (Person Field)
>
> ---------------- txtEmpName (Single line of text)
>
> List B
>   --------- Emp (Lookup on txtEmpName)

In an OOB workflow or via list web service I can usually get the list item ID from the value of the `lookup field` value. I am trying to do this from an Event Receiver but I get the raw text value. See below:

```
using (web) 
{
     SPList list = web.Lists["List B"];

       foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items) 
       {
          //item["emp"] = "1;#Joe Smith"
          if ((int)item["emp"] == properties.ListItemId) 
          { 
               item["OnDeletingOutcome"] = "This Item should be deleted";
               item.Update();
          }
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fetch ID from Lookup field, you can use following code:

```
SPFieldLookupValue fieldLookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue(item["emp"].ToString());
int lookupID = fieldLookupValue.LookupId;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Create a ItemDeleting Event Receiver on List A, Get the value of txtEmpName and its LookUp value using SPFieldLookUpValue as below,

```
SPFieldLookupValue fieldLookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue(item["txtEmpName"].ToString());
int lookupID = fieldLookupValue.LookupId;
```

Now Connect to the List B, and delete the item Where respective to the item in List A, Since you have the LookUpValue and also the EmployeeName You can find the item in List B which has to be deleted, Query that item and delete it. I hope txtEmpName which is acting as foreign key in List A, will be Primary Key in List B. OtherWise it will delete all the other items which has the values of txtEmpName. If this is not the case you need to make values from more columns to make a composite key to find the right item to delete.